# Hubbell-raco receptacle and switch boxes

Tags: electrical

Why doesn't Hubbell-Raco receptacle metal boxes (double gang, single gang, handy boxes--most of their boxes) do not have an 1/2" inch protrusion when affixing it to wood studs to rough in basement or new garages or adding a new room.  Then adding 1/2 inch drywall would fit perfectly. They have a brackets in some cases attached but it does protrude. For example Garvin boxes do have them. The only time that i would think you would have a double gang or 4x4 square box flush with the stud is if your adding mud or raised rings. Would appreciate any insights! Just curious.

Comment: My guess is they are intended for commercial/industrial applications with conduit and construction proceeds differently there. There is no need for ears which locate it on wooden studs. These metal boxes may be nearly always clamped to  drywall or attached to metal brackets rather than attached to wooden studs.

Comment: They make all kinds... *try the next aisle over.* 99% of my work is in conduit, and in the rare case I mount to wooden studs/rafters, I put a 1x4 behind the box spanning 2 joists, and screw the box into it.  Different mentalities!

Comment: Love your answer. Sounds logical! Tha ks

Comment: @JimStewart thanksJim -ithink you are right. Consumer service at Raco didnt know but a tech person will call me will probably call me with the same answer of yours.

Answer (score 1):

How many boxes would you have to manufacture in order to cover everything we use a 4 sq box for. It's just not financially feasible from a manufacturing standpoint. Plus, it would be hard to mount and work inside the box from interference of the plaster ring. So when you say "most of the boxes" you are using them in situations you are working in and does not consider the uses in other types of construction. In fact I would debate that more boxes are used commercially and most of the boxes there are blank covers and you would finish out devices on 5/8" drywall.

Comment: In Illinois conduit is required and so is metal boxes especially in Chicagoland area.the bracket you see is flush at the side of the box for hammering it in or using screws or both. But they dont protrude except for only a fee of their metal switches. Plastic boxes. Ot a problem-- but again cannot be used here. Just curious and appreciated your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the bracket is flush with the front of the box? I just took a quick look at Raco metal switch boxes w/ brackets on a website and they look like the bracket is set back close to 1/2".
Maybe the box you have is meant to be used with a plaster ring.
Why would you use metal switch boxes in a house anyway? You're just making more work for yourself.

Comment: There is a pair of fancy in-burbs in Dallas (Highland  Park and University Park) which require all house wiring in rigid metal conduit and metal boxes. Retrofit work can be with flexible armored cable. We have rats in Dallas which chew the insulation off wires and I know they are everywhere. Our tract house is wired with NM, and there are rats around because I use snap traps but won't use poison.

Comment: Jim it is required to have conduit in Illinois. I wasn't trying to make a big deal about this---but thought it was strange that Hubbell-Raco most of their metal boxes don't have that 1/2" protrusion at home depot and menards. However in plastic it isn't a problem. For example my garage is unfinish and the 4x4 square are mounted flush with the studs including the receptacles.  My utility room also same thing-- flush with the stud. I will call then tomorrow to ask why they don't have many of their boxes except for a couple of switch boxes that way?

Comment: 4" square boxes when surface mounted use a device cover and when used as a wallcase use a plaster ring to finish flush with the wall board. To mount the front edge of a 4" square junction box flush with the wall board wouldn't leave you with any normal way to finish it off that I'm aware of.